# Npm run build is not working, its displaying perfectly on the dev environment(local machine) after npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm-build

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\react2\reacting>npm run build

> reacting@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cat' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'chmod' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cp' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'dirs' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pushd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'popd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'echo' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tempdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pwd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'exec' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ls' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'find' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'grep' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'head' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ln' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mkdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'rm' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mv' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sed' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'set' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sort' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tail' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'test' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'to' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'toEnd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'touch' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'uniq' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:1116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'which' of module exports inside circular dependency

Failed to compile.

Unknown browser query `dead`

Comment: Try this command: `node --trace-warnings <file_name.js>`, you will get where the warning is

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: never mind, my react-scripts were out of date. thanks